# On 1 dispatch, dispatching in an infinite loop react redux with connect mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Here is my code i tried removing `...state` and replacing by comments below but it didn't work when dispatching I'm getting error below

```js
 props.add();
  // props.add();
  // props.add();

  return (
    // <div className="container">
    //   <BrowserRouter>
    //     <Nav />
    //     <Switch>
    //       <Route path="/reg" component={Reg} />
    //       <Route path="/log" component={Log} />
    //     </Switch>
    //   </BrowserRouter>
    // </div>
  );
}

let mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    ...state
    // counter: state.counter,
    // bool: state.bool,
  }
}
let mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    add: () => dispatch(add()),
    rem: () => dispatch(rem()),
    pos: () => dispatch(pos()),
    neg: () => dispatch(neg())
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `add` method is in your render method so this method will get called every time this component is rendered. This in turn will update the store and re-render the component causing the infinite call.

What are you trying to achieve here? Try moving the `add` call to a button click or in `componentDidUpdate` to prevent the infinite calls.

Comment: Oh thanks, I used useEffect and it worked without connect it was working fine without lifeCicles and didn't cause any problem I didn't know it would while with connect :/// thanks in 5 minutes I will mark this answer as correct